# Make an iOS device a bluetooth microphone through CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is it possible to *fake* an iOS device into a bluetooth microphone such that other phones paired and connected to it would have be able to receive audio in real time?

I know it is not possible for Android since the android does not support the sink role in the bluetooth A2DP profile but was wondering if this is possible for iOS since I've seen claims that iOS can become peripherals as well using Core Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CoreBluetooth` framework is for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) usage only. This is perfect for sending sensor data, but the throughput is not enough for audio. The A2DP profile is not part of BLE and iOS provides no access to profiles other than BLE.

Comment: So I was wondering how do those out-of-the-box bluetooth headsets work? I wouldn't need to install any new app for an iOS device that implements profiles like A2DP to enable my bluetooth headset to send voice to the device.

Comment: iOS itself does of course supports the entire Bluetooth stack (currently at v4.1 I believe), including A2DP. However there is no developer access to Bluetooth profiles other than Bluetooth Low Energy. CoreBluetooth is not a general purpose Bluetooth framework, it deals with BLE only.